# How to correctly interpret $\hat{\sigma}_{eg}^i \hat{\sigma}_{ge}^j$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin, quantum-electrodynamics, interactions

I am trying to figure out the [paper of Asenjo-Garcia et al.: PHYS. REV. X 7, 031024 (2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.03382).

Specifically, in e.g. Equation (5):

$$ \mathcal{H}_{eff} = -\mu_0 \omega_0^2 \sum_{i,j = 1}^N \mathbf{D}^* \cdot \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{r_i}, \mathbf{r_j}, \omega_0) \cdot \mathbf{D} \hat{\sigma}_{eg}^i \hat{\sigma}_{ge}^j. $$

The atomic coherence operators appear with superscript i and j for atoms i and j. As I understand it, this is an abbreviation of:

$$ \hat{\sigma}_{eg}^i \hat{\sigma}_{ge}^j = (\mathbf{1} \otimes \mathbf{1} \otimes ... \otimes \hat{\sigma}_{eg} \otimes ... \otimes \mathbf{1}) \cdot (\mathbf{1} \otimes \mathbf{1} \otimes ... \otimes \hat{\sigma}_{ge} \otimes ... \otimes \mathbf{1}) = \mathbf{1} \otimes \mathbf{1} \otimes ... \otimes \hat{\sigma}_{eg} \otimes ... \otimes \hat{\sigma}_{ge} \otimes ... \otimes \mathbf{1} $$

Where the operators act on the respectively i'th and j'th subspace of the systems Hilbert space. However, I cannot make this comply with the dimension of the Hamiltonian, which is supposed to be $N \times N$. If the above abbreviation was correct (in the case of two-level systems) the effective Hamiltionan would have dimension $2^N \times 2^N$, right?

Comment: I briefly scanned the section you're talking about, and I can't see anywhere it suggests that the space is $N$-dimensional. Indeed, it sure seems like the space is $2^N$-dimensional, as you suggest. Where in the paper does it say that the space is $N$-dimensional?

Comment: I seem to have mistaken that they only consider the 50 lowest-energy eigenstates later in the paper (section of finite 1D linear chain) for the dimension of the space. I.e. they consider only 50 states of the N=50 atoms, but the Hamiltonian of course encodes the energies of the entire 2^50 states. So, you would agree that I interpreted the abbreviation above correctly? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have learned it is the correct interpretation of the abbreviation. As march correctly pointed out, the full Hamiltonian is concerned about the 2^N dimensional space, as constructed by the successive tensor products of N two-level systems. The confusion arose, when later in the paper (section III.B), they constrain themselves to only investigate the single-excitation states (there be N such states), for which the Hamiltonian effectively is but a N x N matrix.